# Pymysql don't update table

Tags: python-3.x

i don't know what's wrong

```
def update_user(self, user_id, key, value):
    con = self.connection.create_connection()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE users SET " + key + " = %s WHERE id = %s", [value, user_id])
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    cur.close()
```

DaoManager.user_dao.update_user(session.habbo.id, "machine_id", msg.read_string())

DaoManager:

```
user_dao = None

try:
    user_dao = UserDao(Database())
except Exception as e:
    Logging.error("Error caught (" + __file__  + "): " + str(e))
```

Database:

```
def create_connection(self):
    return pymysql.connect(user="root", password="", host="localhost", database="")
```

The users table is not updated, so I do not know.

Comment: does `tuples = cursor.fetchwarnings()` returns something ?

Comment: fetchwarning does not exist.

Comment: If You could add more info, about database type, connector module etc. It would help us to support You.

Comment: I've updated the Question.

Comment: Noone any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you run a select on that row?